# How to escape a NULL byte as an argument to a shell command inside a Makefile

Tags: shell, null, makefile, escaping

Inside a Makefile I run a shell command which I want to pass a NULL byte as argument. The following attempt fails:

```
echo $(shell /bin/echo -n $$'\x00' | ruby -e "puts STDIN.read.inspect")
```

It generates:

```
echo "$\\x00"
```

Instead I expected:

```
echo "\u0000"
```

How do I properly escape such a NULL byte?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to the execve(2) semantics it is not possible to pass a string containing a null byte as argument. Each argument string is terminated by null byte, therefore making it impossible to distinguish between the contained null byte and the end of the string.

Comment: No, was trying to use `file --print0 | cut`, using now `file -F "/" | cut -d "/"` instead.

Comment: use `cut -z/--zero-terminated`

Answer (score 11):

`echo` disables interpretation of backslash escapes by default.  You need to supply the `-e` option to enable it.

```
$ echo -ne "\x00" | ruby -e "puts STDIN.read.inspect"
"\u0000"
```

Comment: I am not interested in passing null bytes over pipes, but in passing them directly inside arguments.

Comment: Oh! So you need to state clearly what you intend to do.  The various answers attempt to address the issue you **describe**.

Comment: Let me quote from my question: >which I want to pass a NULL byte as **argument** <

Comment: Which was substantiated with an example.

Comment: Feel free to delete your answer if you dislike having written a downvoted answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91124/etiquette-on-removing-wrong-answer-after-a-downvote

Comment: `bash` (and I believe most `sh`?) ignores null bytes in command substitution, so it's a no-go unless you pipe. There's no need for `echo`. `printf '\0'` is more reliable

Answer (score 2):

These uses of `echo` are totally non-portable.  Use `printf`, it's much easier to use for anything other than the simplest strings, and much more portable.

```
$ cat makefile
all:
        printf '\0' > foo.out
        od -a foo.out

$ make
printf '\0' > foo.out
od -a foo.out
0000000 nul
0000001
```

Comment: If you want a good answer, ask a good question.  Your example showed echoing a NUL byte.  I showed you how to generate a NUL byte.  If that's not what you wanted, then ask the question you want answered.  If you really wanted to know how to split the output of `find -print0` into individual arguments in the shell, then ask THAT question.  Then we could have all immediately explained that such a thing is not useful in the context of breaking up words in a shell script.

Comment: It seems I am unable to come up with a minimal example not drawing the readers thoughts away from my intention. You have enough reputation to edit my question. Please show me an example matching exactly my questions intention of passing a NULL byte as an argument.

Comment: Not being able to come up with a good example is the first hint of trouble.  At least describe at a higher level what you're trying to accomplish.  Elsewhere you mention sending the output of `find -print0` into `cut`... but then what?  Where does the output of `cut` go?  Wherever it goes, obviously it won't be delimited by NUL bytes anymore so essentially `-print0` is useless.  Fundamentally, `-print0` is only helpful if the final consumer of the output can _itself_ split on NUL bytes: the shell cannot do that.  Here we don't know what that consumer is so we can't advise.

Comment: I assumed it was a good thing to limit the question to the small specific detail I have trouble with. Maybe next time I will ask: "I am trying to achieve world peace. The 1.000.000 lines of code I have written can be viewed at http://bla.bla.bla/. Please fix my code!!!"

Answer (score 1):

### You can't use `NUL` as argument in bash

You can't use `$'\0'` as an argument, store it as a variable or using command substitution `$(printf '\0')` since `bash` (and most shells?) use C-strings that are null terminated. The leading string before `NUL` is interpreted as the string and the trailing string discarded.

You can only input using pipes - `printf '\0' | cat -v` or letting the resulting program use a file for input.

### Use another means of input

Most programs that work on input with line strings `NUL` strings (`xargs`, `cut`, ...) typically have a `-z` flag. This is primarily used when dealing with paths as a character may contain ANY character EXCEPT `NUL`.

Programs like `find` and `git ls-files` support outputting this format, usually in the form of a `-print0` or `-0` flag.

Programs like `sed`, `tr`, `bash` et. al. use special escape characters like `\0`, `\x0`, `\x00` to generate `NUL` bytes.

### Massage the input

OP originally seems to have wanted to know how to [use `cut` with a `NUL` delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9848445/1507124). The problem is typically that something is separated using `\n`, where `\n` is a valid part of the values and not a line-separator (typically in paths).

Say you have a situation where you group files, each separated by a `NUL` character, and the groups separated by `\n`.

```sh
# Temporary mock output with NUL columns and newline rows
printf 'foo\0bar\nbar\0\nFOO\0BAR\0\n' > /tmp/$$.output
```

A work-around is to get creative with a combination of `sed`, `awk` or `tr` to massage the output to something that suits our input/commands.

#### our.sed

```
#!/usr/bin/sed -nf

# beginning
:x 
# match \0\n
/\x0$/ {
 # Change \0\n to \n
 s|\x0$|\n|g
 # print
 p
 # delete
 d
}
# match \n with no leading \0
/[^\x0]$/ {
 # change \0 to \1
 s|\x0|\x1|g
 # read next line
 N
 # branch to beginning
 bx
}
```

In this scenario we map:

- `\0\n` => `\n`
- `\0` not followed by `\n` => `\1`
  While a valid character in a filename, it's unlikely to pose a problem.

```sh
# Change NUL to another unlikely to be used control character
sed -f our.sed /tmp/$$.output |\
  cut -d $'\x1' -f 2
```

output

```
bar
BAR
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else came here looking how to escape a null via a shell command in ruby backticks:

```
irb(main):024:0> `curl --silent http://some-website-or-stream.com | sed 's/\\x0//g' 1>&2`
=> ""
```