# Escaped string of bytes to bytestring

Tags: python, string, byte

I'm new to Python and I need to read bytestring from a command line argument. I'm using Python 3.4.

At the moment, I'm using argparse to parse the arguments, with this configuration for the data: `parser.add_argument("-d", "--data", default=b'\0')`

When I call my program with -d argument (e.g. `python myprogram.py -d b'd\x00!\x00W\x00'`), it interprets the value of -d as a string, escaping slashes and treating the 'b' as part of the string, like this: `'b\\'d\\x00!\\x00W\\x00\\''`

Is there a way to unescape the output from argparse and convert it to bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd normally have the shell formulate the exact bytes, but since you [cannot pass in NUL bytes as arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105225/how-to-escape-a-null-byte-as-an-argument-to-a-shell-command-inside-a-makefile) asking users to pass in escape sequences is a reasonable work-around.

However, the shell is not going to interpret Python byte string literal notation.

In this case, I'd ask the user to enter *hexadecimal* values instead:

```
python myprogram.py -d "64 00 21 00 57 00"
```

and use the [`binascii.unhexlify()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify) to produce your `bytes` value from that (removing any whitespace first):

```
whitespace = dict.fromkeys((9, 10, 13, 32))  # tab, space, newline and carriage return
data = binascii.unhexlify(args.data.translate(whitespace))
```

This does require that you set your default argument value to a compatible value:

```
parser.add_argument("-d", "--data", default='00')
```

The alternative would be to use the [`ast.literal_eval()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to interpret the Python byte string literal syntax:

```
data = ast.literal_eval(args.data)
```

and your default'd be:

```
parser.add_argument("-d", "--data", default=repr(b'\0'))
```

but take into account that this function accepts any Python literal, so you could end up with any other object type, including numbers, strings and containers.

Comment: @thefourtheye: which doesn't help anything here because that doesn't handle interpreting escape sequences. You also still cannot pass in a NUL byte as `sys.argv` value.

Comment: Yup, I was about to add that bug was not helpful, but my browser won't allow me for some reason. I ll remove that.