# Passing argument containg nullbyte (\x00) to subprocess.call

Tags: linux, python-2.7, subprocess, rhel

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import call

try:
    call(['echo', "aabbccddee".decode('hex')])
    print 'Input without \\x00 works!'
except Exception as e:
    print 'Input without \\x00 throws exception: ' + str(e)

try:
    call(['echo', "aabbccdd00ee".decode('hex')]) # The input contains \x00
    print 'Input with \\x00 works!'
except Exception as e:
    print 'Input with \\x00 throws exception: ' + str(e)
```

Returns the following (tested with Python 2.7 on RHEL 6):

```
▒▒▒▒▒
Input without \x00 works!
Input with \x00 throws exception: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings
```

Questions:

- Is this expected behavior by `subprocess.call` or might this be a bug?
- Is there any way I can pass binary data (directly) containing \x00 to another executable within a python script? *It will probably work using shell=True, but I would prefer another way, if there is any.*

Note:

- `>>> type("00".decode('hex'))
  <type 'str'>`
- Running `echo $'\x00'` directly works as expected.

**EDIT**

This seems to be correct behavior after more research. [Due to the execve(2) semantics it is not possible to pass a string containing a null byte as argument.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105225/how-to-escape-a-null-byte-as-an-argument-to-a-shell-command-inside-a-makefile)

See:

- `$ echo $'\x55\x55\x55\x00\x55\x55'
  UUU`

However, I couldn't really find anymore info on this (second question especially, as it seems shell=True won't help either (all data after the null byte wouldn't be passed)). I leave this question open for a while, maybe someone can provide a deeper insight or share some useful resources on this.